# How does an inductor not having any current through it resist change in current?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

when a steady current is set up in an inductor, it has some energy associated with it due to the magnetic field set up. it uses this energy to resist changes in current .then how does an inductor which is disconnected from any cell and has no current through it, hence no energy in it, resist change in current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are asking how current is opposed in an inductor through which no current is flowing at the time. To start any current you will need to connect a source of emf, such as a battery, across the inductor. As soon as the current starts, magnetic flux is linked with the inductor and the changing magnetic flux induces an emf in the coil, opposing that due to the battery.

Energy is included indirectly in this answer, insofar as emf can be defined as energy transferred per unit charge passing. But "How does...?" questions aren't always best answered in terms of energy. Instead: think informally of emfs as electromotive *forces* acting on the charges in the inductor – one from the battery and one (due to the $\vec E$ in the Maxwell equation $\nabla \times \vec E=-\frac{\partial {\vec B}}{\partial t}$) from the changing flux. You should now have a force-picture of how the change in current is opposed. Finally put the record straight and recall that the electromotive *force* has to act through a distance in order to be called an emf and to be measured in volt.

Comment: *something* is not right with your equation.

Comment: Thank you so much. The equation got mutilated...

Answer (score 5):

> it uses this energy to resist changes in current

This is incorrect. It does not require any energy from the inductor to "resist" changes in current.

I do not like the word "resist" in this context because an inductor is not a resistor. In my opinion you should not ever use the word "resist" to describe the behavior of an inductor.

The inductance itself ensures that $$v(t)=L \frac{d}{dt}i(t)$$ That is simply what defines an inductor. So the correct terminology is that a changing current induces a voltage across an inductor, or a voltage across it induces a changing current through the inductor. You should consistently use the "induce" terminology instead of the "resist" terminology for an inductor.

In some cases the voltage is induced as energy is delivered to the inductor, and in other cases the same voltage is induced as energy is pulled from the inductor. The relationship between voltage and current, induction, does not depend on the direction of energy flow nor on the amount of energy already stored or not. It is completely irrelevant whether the energy is zero or not. The induction relationship above holds always.